# Store search results for later use - Accessing results view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a c# asp.net MVC project. I am doing a a search and want to access the search results on the details page of one of the search results.

This is so that I can have `< prev | next >` links on the detail pages that will link to the next property in the last search results.

My approach so far is to put the search results object into a session variable, but I can't figure out the code to actually access it. When I do a watch on `Session["SearchResults"]` below, I can see the records in the `Result View`, which seems to hold an array.

I know someone is going to tell me I'm thinking about this all wrong, and I can't wait to be enlightened.

Someone suggested I should just store the last search results on the repository as a public property, would that be a better option? Or can someone recommend an altogether better way of doing what I need to do?

This is my controller

```
public ActionResult Search(int? page, Search search)
{

    search.regusApi =  Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["regusApiLiveInventory"]);
    Session["SearchResults"] = MeetingRoomRepositoryWG.Search(search).AsPagination(page ?? 1, 7);

    return View(new SearchResultsWG { SearchCriteria = search, Locations = MeetingRoomRepositoryWG.Search(search).AsPagination(page ?? 1, 7) });
}

public ActionResult NiceDetails(String suburb, String locationName, int id)
{
        **Here I want to acceess the session variable**

        return View(MeetingRoomRepositoryWG.RoomDetails(id).First());
}
```

Here is the code from the repository:

```
public static List<Location> Search(Search search)
{

    String LongLatString = search.LongLat;
    LongLatString = LongLatString.Substring(1, LongLatString.Length - 2);

    var LonLatSplit = LongLatString.Split(',');
    var latitude = Convert.ToDecimal(LonLatSplit[0]);
    var longitude = Convert.ToDecimal(LonLatSplit[1]);

    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        var query = context.Locations.Include("Location_LonLats").ToList();

        query.OrderBy(x => (Convert.ToDecimal(x.Location_LonLats.Lat) - latitude) * (Convert.ToDecimal(x.Location_LonLats.Lat) - latitude)
                 + (Convert.ToDecimal(x.Location_LonLats.Lon) - longitude) * (Convert.ToDecimal(x.Location_LonLats.Lon) - longitude));

        return query;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how large the data is you search against but, it's better to not store search results at all. It will scale very poorly and become a resource hog quite easily. Why store e.g. 500 pages of search results if the user only ends up looking at 1 or 3? 
How long are you going to hold these potentially large result sets in session storage? For how many users?

Just do a page based search, essentially redoing the search for each "next" click the client does. A good index or something like Lucene.net can help if your searches are too slow.

Comment: Not sure the number of users yet, but you're right it might not scale well. If I pass the search and re do it when they click next, I will need to know what search result they clicked on in the first place. I guess I could store the result number they clicked on on the search results page. I don't know how I would do that since, with pagination, how would I know what search result they clicked on? Even with this information, I would some how have to access the search results in the same form as the above...(which I haven't been able to do so far)....

Comment: Could include your search parameters in the URL of your 'next' and 'previous' links. Or make your next and previous buttons do form post and include the search parameters as form data. An Ajax call is possible also.

Comment: If you make your Search method return an IEnumerable and return your data using yield you can do pagination a lot easier using Linq. Only skipping of results is going to be suboptimal. Best would be if you can include a Skip and Take parameter in the call somehow. Your ordering of the search result is unfortunate, you'd need to index it pre-ordered.